# How is [UITextField rac_newTextChannel] used to two-way bind UITextField text to a model object in ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Say I have the following:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

and a model object:

```
JSModel *model = [[JSModel alloc] init];
```

The following will give me a two-way binding (perhaps there are disadvantages with this approach that I'm not seeing?):

```
RAC(model, text) = textField.rac_textSignal;
RAC(textField, text) = RACObserve(model, text);
```

How can `[UITextField rac_newTextChannel]` be used to achieve this two-way binding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
RACChannelTerminal *textFieldTerminal = [self.textField rac_newTextChannel];
RACChannelTerminal *modelTerminal = RACChannelTo(self.model, text);
[modelTerminal subscribe:textFieldTerminal];
[[textFieldTerminal skip:1] subscribe:modelTerminal];
```